What is the plausible excuse (אמתלא) of “על ידי נתינה”
In Talmudic jargon, an אמתלא is a “ plausible reason for correcting or retracting an evidence.”:

אֲמַתְלָא (Y. מַתְלָא) m. (cmp. h. משל) something tangible (= דבר שיש בו ממש); plausible reason for correcting or retracting an evidence. Keth. 22ᵃ אם נתנה א׳ וכ׳ if she offers a reasonable explanation of her contradictory statements, her second one is accepted. Gitt. IX, 9 ובלבד שלא יהא שם א׳ provided no reasonable explanation is offered to show how the report may have arisen by mistake; a. fr. V. מַתְלָא.

In Simla Chadasha 1:40, he talks about a shochet explaining that he didn’t mean it when he told someone the meat was not kosher (I’m going to translate the boldd part below):

טבח שעשה סימן בראש הכבש השחוט שיהא נראה שהוא טריפה וגם אמר שהוא טריפה ואח"כ אמר שכשר היה ושלא אמר כן אלא שלא יקחו אותו אחרים וישאר לו ליקח ממנו כשר כיון שנתן אמתלא לדבריו נאמן. ונ"ל דה"ה באומר טעיתי בדין זה בדבר הראוי לטעות בו עוד נ"ל דדוקא שבשעה שהחזיקה בטריפה היה מקום אמתלא כגון שיש דוחק בבשר ולשוחט צריך לו בשר או שהבהמה של גוי והשוחט אינו מפוייס עמו או מחמת נתינה וכדומה באופן שלא הוחזקה בהמה זו בעיני השומעים ורואה הסימן לטריפה וודאית בלי פקפוק אף על גב דמכל מקום אסורה היא כ"ז שלא חזר בו השוחט מכל מקום עדיין רשות בידו להחזיקה בכשירה באמירת אמתלא אבל אם בשעת אמירתו ומעשה שלו לא נשאר שום ספק בלב השומעים והוחזקה בעיני כל לטריפה ודאית לאו כל כמיניה דהשוחט דכל מידי דאתחזק באסורא א"א להוציאה מחזקה אלא בראיה ברורה ואפילו בלא עשיית מעשה רק באמירה שאמר טריפה היא ולא היה מקום אמתלא והוחזקה בטריפה וודאית בהוחלט חוכך אני להחמיר שלא להאמינו אחר כך להכשירו באמתלא ויש להחמיר בשל תורה:


…And it further appears to me the Amasla only works if at the time the shochet declared it trief, an excuse was a possibility. If, for example, there was a shortage of meat and shochet needed meat for himself, or if the animal belonged to a non-Jew and the shochet was not happy with the person he told the meat was treif, or because of נתינה and the like.

The part about the “animal belonged to a non-Jew and the shochet was not happy with the person he told the meat was treif” is based on a Gemara in chullin, end of 94B and on, see below, but what does “על ידי נתינה” mean? What is the plausible excuse?

ההוא טבחא דא"ל לחבריה.
§ The Gemara returns to the topic of selling non-kosher meat to a gentile. There was a certain Jewish butcher who said to another individual:


אי הוות פייסת מינאי מי לא ספיי לך משור של פטם דעבדי אתמול א"ל אכלי משופרי שופרי א"ל מנלך א"ל דזבן פלוני עובד כוכבים וספא לי א"ל תרי עבדי וההוא טרפה הוה
If you would have made peace with me yesterday, wouldn’t I have given you a cut from the fattened bull that I prepared yesterday? The other individual said to him: Nevertheless I ate from the finest of the fine of that bull that you prepared. The butcher said to him: From where did you get a piece? The other said to him: So-and-so the gentile bought it and fed it to me. The butcher said to him: I prepared two bulls yesterday. One was kosher, but that one you ate was a tereifa, which is why I sold it to a gentile.


איכא דאמרי אמר רבי מפני שוטה זה דאיכוון לצעוריה לחבריה אנו נאסור כל
המקולין
The Gemara presents an alternate version of Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi’s reaction to the incident cited above: There are those who say that Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi said: Because of this imbecile, who intended only to cause distress to his fellow, should we forbid all of the meat from gentile butcher shops? That butcher was presumably lying about the meat having been from a tereifa.


You seem to have the answer in your second part. Just like he tried to aggrieve his fellow by stating directly that it's trefa, so he tried to aggrieve his fellow by giving it to a non-Jew at a lower price, implicitly indicating that it's not kosher. What's the question?

@YDJ. I’m not following your logic. Are you saying that “על ידי נתינה” is another aspect of “אינו מפייס עמו ” ? I think it makes more sense that the או is a new clause, just like the previous two. Also, the shochet says it is tried, then gives it to a goy. How does that prove that he was really lying.

@YDJ thinking about it, it is possible ״על ידי נתינה״  means that after he declared it treif he gave it to someone for safekeeping. His argument is that which he said it was trief, you can tell he really didn’t mean it because he gave it to someone to guard for him when he declared it treif.

In the case if the shochet gives 2 pieces, a kosher and a non-kosher to a non-Jew on condition to give the kosher piece to a Jew, the carrier might be interested in keeping the kosher one, as more expensive, for himself. As you say, the shochet can declare both pieces non-kosher to prevent replacement. If the shochet is angry with the Jewish customer, to whom he is sending the piece, he can claim after the fact that the piece was non-kosher.

And even if he did not declare it non-kosher, due to possibility of replacement, the shochet can claim that by giving meat to a non-Jewish carrier, he indicated that it was non-kosher.
